# Using Boomi to cut variable length string at first white space

Tags: javascript, string, function, boomi

I have a list of consignors that have a variable ID number at the beginning of their name followed by a space and would like to remove the number and first space.

I do not see a string function that will do it. The cut function doesn't work because the line has multiple spaces.  For example, if I have "1234 My house" I want it to be "My house" The second space is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at is replace a leading number plus white space with nothing.

```
str = str.replace(/^\d+\s*/, '');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I'm not able to get it to work in Boomi.  I'm treating the input as the original string, the regex expression as the String to Search, and I have nothing tied to the String to Replace.